# Maven, configure specific goal

Tags: java, maven-2

I want to configure "exploded" goal of the maven-war-plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>exploded</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <webappDirectory>war</webappDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I need to run "exploded" goal manually and do not want to attach execution to any lifycycle phase. But when i execute "mvn war:exploded", maven ignores my configuration. Tell me please, how to do this :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Read this page for reference:

[Guide to Configuring Default Mojo Executions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html)

In essence:

it will work if you configure the execution with the id `default-cli`

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-cli</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>exploded</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <webappDirectory>war</webappDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you! You have solved my problem! I read the text by link above, but probably with not enough attention :)

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain a little more? What would the command look like to invoke this?